# A function to get which number shall 2 be raised to to get x

Tags: c#, math

Find x in 2^x = n.
This is what I am trying to do.(It is not for any specific purpose. It just looks good.)
This is what I wrote but it doesn't work.

```
       public double f(double x)
       {
            double result = 0;
            double increaser = 1;
            
            double subtract = result - increaser;
            double add = result + increaser;
            
            while(true)
            {
                if((Math.Pow(2,result) == x) || increaser == 0.0001) 
                {
                    break;
                }
                
                double sP = Math.Abs(Math.Pow(2,subtract) - x);
                double aP = Math.Abs(Math.Pow(2,add) - x);
                double nP = Math.Abs(Math.Pow(2,result) - x);
                
                if((sP < nP) && (sP < aP))
                {
                    result -= increaser;
                }
                else if((aP < nP) && (aP < sP))
                {
                    result += increaser;
                }
                else if((nP < sP) && (nP < aP))
                {
                    increaser = increaser / 10;
                }
            }
            
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: One of the reasons your function doesn't work is your `if, else if, else if` statement. When you run your program it goes in to an endless loop because none of the conditions match.

Comment: Is your aim to write your own log function?

Answer (score 3):

This function is called the logarithm:

```
return Math.Log2(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, you can use two formulae for this:

- if `bx = n`, then `x = logbn`; and
- `logba = logxa/logxb`.

Since what you're looking for is `x` in `2x = n`, that is `x = log2n = logen/loge2`, something that can be done with:

```c
public double f(double x) {
    return Math.Log(x) / Math.Log(2);
}
```

Of course, that's for the case where you have a limited set of logarithm bases (such as `10` or `e`). Since C# provides a call that will handle any base, you can bypass the division operation:

```c
public double f(double x) {
    return Math.Log(x, 2);
}
```

or even use the base-2 one:

```c
public double f(double x) {
    return Math.Log2(x);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not yet been taught logarithms in school yet. So, I did not know this. I thoight why isn't there a formula for this and searching didnt help.